# how to compute the compound probability of multiple independent events?

Tags: probability, probability-distribution, probability-theory

for example, I have 7 customer bookings in a day, each with an independent probability of show up. So what is the probability of only 1 customer show up? only 2 customers show up? only 3 customers show up? etc. How to compute this type of problem, is there any generalized equation or formula ?

| Customer | Probability of show up | Probability of not show up |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.3 | 0.7 |
| B | 0.4 | 0.6 |
| C | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| D | 0.6 | 0.4 |
| E | 0.7 | 0.3 |
| F | 0.8 | 0.2 |

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any formula, but you can calculate the probabilities of n customers turning up like this:

Let p[i] be the probability of customer i turning up.
Let Q( N, n) be the probability that, if we consider just customers 0,..N-1, then n of them turn up.

We have

```
Q( 1, 0) = 1.0-p[0]
Q( 1, 1) = p[0]
```

And

```
Q( N+1, 0) = (1.0-p[N])*Q(N, 0)
for i=1..N
    Q( N+1, i) = (1.0-p[N])*Q(N, i) + p[N]*Q(N, i-1)
Q( N+1, N+1) = p[N]*Q(N, N)
```

For example, there are two mutually exclusive ways that i of customers 0..N can turn up: either customer N doesn't turn up and i of 0..N-1 do, or N does turn up and i-1 of 0..N-1 do